# Firebase rules - limit access to owning user

Tags: facebook, firebase

My app is using Firebase's Facebook authentication and I have the following **users** collection:

```
{
  "fsdjf34hf98wjefj" : {
    "uid" : "facebook:543634634536"
  },
  "3298djwhy9hwd34234" : {
    "uid" : "facebook:7658899965432"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to restrict access so that a user can view only his own user:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".write": true,
        "users": {
            ".read": "auth.uid === data.child('uid').val()",
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error when trying to access a user from JavaScript:

> Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the
>   desired data.

Does anyone know the correct syntax for the **.read** section? I've tried many things but I don't seem to get the hang of the logic behind it.

Comment: Having the same issue right now! Hope somebody can help - spent 5 hours on it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your collection is:

```
"users": {
  "fsdjf34hf98wjefj" : {
    "uid" : "facebook:543634634536"
  },
  "3298djwhy9hwd34234" : {
    "uid" : "facebook:7658899965432"
  }
}
```

Your rules will need to be something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === data.child('uid').val()",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `$user` in there applies to *every user node*.

Note that the easiest way to troubleshoot such issues is by using the Simulator tab in the Firebase dashboard to simulate the operation. It will tell you exactly *why* the operation is allowed/rejected, while the SDK will (intentionally) only tell you *that* the operation was rejected.

Comment: Thanks, I was also accessing the users collection directly, and then filtering it to the one I need. That's why I was getting an error, because I can't view all -- only my own :)